# How to modify order of tabbed windows in XMonad?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm using [tabbed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Layout-Tabbed.html) and I would like to change behavior so that the new window is created on the right side (like browser tabs).

I see no easy way to do this. Do I need to write a new layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Hooks-InsertPosition.html

You need to set this on your config's `manageHook`:

```
import XMonad.Hooks.InsertPosition

... manageHook = insertPosition End Newer <+> myManageHook
```

The type signature of `insertFunction` is `Position -> Focus -> ManageHook`. In plain English:  it is a function that takes a `Focus` and `Position` (in this case `End` and `Newer`), and it returns a `ManageHook`.

Comment: Awesome! I recalling visiting that page, but couldn't figure out what any of those enums mean. If you happen to know, can you please expand the answer?

Comment: Sorry my bad it should be `End Newer` instead of `Master Newer`.